# Android: How to let a server know a user is still online?

Tags: android

I'm building an android app where the server needs to know if the user is still online or not.
You can compare it with facebook chat on android. If the user is on the app, other users can see he is online. But when the user loses internet connection or closes the app the server needs to know he is not online anymore.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Send a heartbeat every once in a while? (I don't think there's any "magic" solution here. Do you have a specific implementation question?)

Comment: Do you mean for example sending a post to a php script like every 30 seconds?

Comment: @KenVernaillen: I beleive sending post to the server like you wrote is the only way, but I'll be glad to here if anybody here could open our eyes to something new we don't know about

Comment: primarily a heartbeat and perhaps a log off onPause() in the activity.

Comment: @KenVernaillen, hey, have you solve this issue ? I am looking for same thing.

Comment: @JeetenParmar I've put an answer how I solved my issue.

Comment: What would be the best way in order to the server to know that the android device is still online/connected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your server type. For example if you use `sip` you can do this by sending registration message before expire time.

But in general the common practice is to send a `keep_alive` message within a short interval. if you use any third party standard server then read their documentation and apply that way. If you are planning to create your own server system then just create a custom `keep_alive` message format and send it to server at regular interval.

Answer (score 1):

@Jeeten Parmar

An easy way to implement a keep_alive system is by using MQTT.
MQTT is a machine-to-machine internet protocol.

http://www.eclipse.org/paho/

When you implement Paho in an Android project, you can subscribe to an MQTT server.
When the client disconnects from the internet, an event can be called. You can even set a lastwill message.

You can also set the keep alive interval. ->

http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/dw/webservices/ws-mqtt/mqtt-v3r1.html#keep-alive-timer